# C++ char array size limit using cin

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ but I don't understand if the char arrays (C-strings) have a limit.

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int MAX = 10;
    char str[MAX];

    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin >> str;

    cout << "Your string is: " << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I write into my console there is no limit on how much characters I can write and save. Is this correct?

My first thought was str wouldn't be able to save more than 10 characters. But I was able to save long strings without a problem.

I'm compiling with g++ in windows 11.

Thanks!

Comment: *But I was able to save long strings without a problem.* -- You caused a buffer overrun when you did that.  That is a *huge* problem.  Many exploits and hacks of code were done by doing a buffer overrun.  When you write out-of-bounds, the behavior of the code is *undefined*.

Comment: C++ doesn't have any kind of built-in bounds-checking. It's up to you as the programmer to make sure that your code doesn't do bad things. Like using `std::string` for all your strings.

Comment: Note - using compile time constants in UPPERCASE is antipattern and creates problems.

Comment: *My first thought was str wouldn't be able to save more than 10 characters.*  Your first thought was in error. *But I was able to save long strings without a problem.*  Your second thought was also in error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no buffer overrun since c++20 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes it does have ;) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2

Comment: Yes, but if the OP claims they saved all the data they typed in, I guess they are not using C++20.

Comment: Is there a reason for limiting the string length to 10 characters?

Comment: Lots of your problems go away if you move over to actually using C++'s `std:;string` the type of code you use is what you would do in "C". The string is then allocated on the heap and can be as large as your heap allows.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm learning C++ and trying to understand the language. My question is about why it allows more than 10 characters if I typed in str declaration a size of 10. There is no clear reason to only limit to 10 characters.

Comment: It allows more than 10 characters because C++ (nor "C") don't babysit you. The compiler expects you to know what you are doing. This assumption is where a lot of the efficiency of C++ comes from, but with great power... ;)

Comment: And since that is a continuous source of bugs (you might lookup undefined behavior) C++ actually has added support with classes like std::string, std::string_view, std::vector and more to help programmers avoid these kind of "out of bound" bugs. A C++ program that compiles doesn't have to be a correct program.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Oh, didn't know that (or I glanced over it without really seeing it). That's really needed! But of course is limited to actual arrays, and few people tend to pass around array references and instead use array-decay to get pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read into a character array before C++20, you need to specify the width, or else you risk writing out of bounds. You need to `#include <iomanip>` and then use [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw):

```cpp
std::cin >> std::setw(MAX) >> str;
```

Since C++20 the `operator>>` overload that takes a `char*` has been removed and replaced with a function template that only accepts `char` arrays with known bound, so you don't need `std::setw(MAX)` since C++20.

Regarding *"I was able to save long strings without a problem."*: When doing that, the program has *undefined behavior* and could crash - or worse, do something else that affects your program in very unpredictable ways.

Comment: But, is it intended that a long string can be stored in the str[10] array? Or just a characteristic of my C++ compiler?

Comment: @CrisHeredia00 No, it's not intended. If you write more characters that there's space for, you write out of bounds. Your program then has _undefined behavior_ and could do just about anything. if happens to write into memory allocated by your program, it may overwrite something important that makes the program misbehave. If it writes to memory to which your program doesn't have access, the program will likely crash. You should _never_ write out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Until C++20, the `>>` overload you are calling is the following (actually there are 3 of them, for `signed char`,`char`, and the character type of the stream in case it is another type):

```
template< class CharT, class Traits>
basic_istream<CharT, Traits>&
operator>>( basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& st, CharT* s );
```

If the user enters a string longer than the array, you invoke *undefined behavior*.

Since C++20, the above is replaced by this overload:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, std::size_t N >
basic_istream<CharT, Traits>&
operator>>( basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& st, CharT (&s)[N] );
```

This overload is aware of the array and never writes more than `N` characters to the array.

For details, I refer you to [operator>>(std::basic_istream)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2).